# How can i tune below proc either by changing query or adding index

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014, index-tuning, performance-tuning

I am having issues with one of the proc running very slow approx an hour:

Please pardon as I have to write entire code out of system to paste here. I will be editng the question with more details on the table schema and indexes as i get to copy that info:

SP is something like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp1]
@parameter1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@parameter2 DATETIME

AS

DECLARE @Today DATETIME =GETDATE()
IF @parameter2 IS NULL
 SET @parameter2 = Getdate()

SET @parameter2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @parameter2 , 101)

DECLARE @table1 TABLE ( tabletypeID BIGINT)

Insert into @table1
SELECT Value from stringsplit(@parameter1, '|')

UPDATE bigtable
    SET value1 = 33, statusdate = @today
from 
    bigtable t
    INNER JOIN anotherbigtable t1 on t.id=t1.id
    INNER JOIN @table1 t3 on t.tabletypeid = t3.tabletypeid
WHERE
    t1.paydate <= @parameter2
    AND t.value1=32
    AND t1.payid =2
```

`bigtable`  is approx 800 M rows and has clustered as PK on id and NC on userid( 1st key), tabletypeid (2nd key)

`anotherbigtable`  is approx. 300 M rows

`@parameter2` is most of times received as NULL while @parameter1 varies

cached plan looks something like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is avoid using table variables in heavy SQL operations. You should use a temp table instead. Either initially or select your table variable @table1 into a temp table then use that temp table in your update statement.

Table variables are historically known to be bottlenecks because statistics aren't maintained on them, and even with Microsoft's improvements to them in SQL 2014 they can still perform poorly. Here's a good Brent Ozar article about them: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/

You might also benefit from using the force seek hint on "anotherbg table". But start with the above change first.

For reference: http://nisalbi.blogspot.com/2015/11/what-is-forceseek-and-forcescan-table.html?m=1

And MS Docs on Table Hints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Typically query hints should only be used in very situational cases by people with experience, but I have found that with larger tables, sometimes the SQL Engine attempts to do an index scan when an index seek truly is a better choice. (Updating the table statistics on "anotherbg table" might more naturally fix your issue too.)

So it's situational and you'll need to test but it's possible a force seek index hint will help.

This is what your update query would look like with the index hint:

```
UPDATE bigtable
    SET value1 = 33, statusdate = @today
from 
    bigtable t
    INNER JOIN anotherbigtable t1 WITH (FORCESEEK) on t.id=t1.id
    INNER JOIN @table1 t3 on t.tabletypeid = t3.tabletypeid
WHERE
    t1.paydate <= @parameter2
    AND t.value1=32
    AND t1.payid =2
```

Comment: @JD thank you so much for taking time and explaining. We discussed internally about table variables but we were told those table variable hold hardly 200 rows. So do you think it will be still worth changing to temp table? Also which index would forceseek hint use? As far as i know there is no index to suffice in where clause predicates. Are you referring to that as Clustered index seek?

Comment: @Newbie-DBA No problem! So historically, it didn't matter if you had only 10 rows in a table variable, the lack of statistics caused SQL to inaccurately estimate the cardinality. Again, 2014 has some improvements, but I've experienced issues even with only 2 records in a table variable and it's generally recommended best practice to avoid them. In your example query, a temp table will make no logical difference and can only help performance so it's basically a freebie to change to a temp table. The FORCESEEK hint will still allow the SQL Engine to choose the index it thinks is best.

Comment: In some cases, the query truly can't be seeked and you'll get an error (which is why I mentioned this is a more advanced technique and should definitely be tested first.) So definitely start with changing the table variable into a temp table first, and maybe looking into updating the statistics on "anotherbigtable" Then you can try adding the FORCESEEK hint. Also pay attention to the execution plan if you test using the FORCESEEK hint. Sometimes the other index seek will get changed to a scan. If that happens you can try applying the FORCESEEK hint to both tables referenced in the join clause.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @J.D. said about temp table variables. Because until SQL Server 2019 version, Query Engine thinks the estimate of temp table variables only returns one row.

Otherwise, I think you should leave also `Clustered Index Scan` on `anotherbigtable`.  Because it cost **98%**

I didn't know your indexes, but I recommend the index below.

```
CREATE INDEX paydate_payid_inc ON anotherbigtable (paydate,payid) INCLUDE (id);
```

Also, not big necessary but I don't like it.

```
SET @parameter2 = Getdate()
    
SET @parameter2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @parameter2 , 101)
```

Please try this.

```
SET @parameter2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101)
```

BTW, you can share your execution plan with [pasttheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), so we can see a lot of information of your query (estimates,cost etc.) and we can write a more powerful answer.